# All threads in jmeter gets completed but the console info is updating for more than 2 hour

Tags: jmeter

I run a performance test with load 25 users with jmeter integrated with jenkins.Once the build is triggered all my thread groups are completed but the console process is running for close to 2 hours.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuQPI.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your image I see 500 users, not 25.

Also I see that 498 users have finished and 2 are still running.

I cannot state for sure why they are running, it's more a question to you. I can think of the following reasons:

1. You're not following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. JMeter lacks resources and got stuck i.e. in endless [garbage collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) (which is a subset of point 1)
3. JMeter waits for response from the server and the server fails to respond. By default JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) samplers don't have any timeout defined and it means that JMeter will wait forever, so make sure to set reasonable connect/response timeouts, the setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler (or better use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) so you could set the timeout for all the HTTP Request samplers in one shot)

   [image]
4. If nothing helps you can check what exactly threads are doing and where they're stuck by taking a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump)